# d3js pan with touchpad or mousewheel pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I've created zoom behaviour with d3js

```
const zoom = d3
      .zoom<SVGSVGElement, unknown>()
      .filter(function (event) {
        return event.which === 2 || event.type === 'wheel';
      })
      .scaleExtent([-10, 10])
      .on('zoom', handleZoom);
```

if i press the mousewheel and move the mouse then pan works, but on touchpad if i put two fingers on the touchpad and move them in the same direction i expect pan effect but zoom works instead. Is there some way to filter the event for pan using touchpad?

```js
const { useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  
  const handleZoom = (event) => {
      d3.select('#group').attr('transform', event.transform);
  }
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    const zoom = d3
      .zoom()
      .filter(function (event) {
        return event.which === 2 || event.type === 'wheel';
      })
      .scaleExtent([-10, 10])
      .on('zoom', handleZoom);
      d3.select('#workflow').call(zoom)
  }, [handleZoom])
  
  return (
    <svg id="workflow">
      <g id="group">
        <foreignObject x="100" y="50">
           <div>Node 1</div>
        </foreignObject>
        <foreignObject x="200" y="150">
           <div>Node 2</div>
        </foreignObject>
      </g>
    </svg>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('app')
);

root.render(<App/>)
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, #app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#workflow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

foreignObject {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: visible;
}


foreignObject > div {
 padding: 10px;
 background-color: #c0c0c0;
 border-radius: 10px;
 width: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I want to set up d3 to work by scrolling the mouse wheel or zoom in/out on the touchpad, and pan to work by holding down the mouse wheel or moving two fingers on the touchpad in the same direction